# How is MOVSX instruction sign extending input in this case?

Tags: assembly, x86, disassembly, sign-extension, zero-extension

I have the following disassembly:

[dest] = d5 cd e8 ca 68

```
movzx   eax, [ebp+dest]
# value of edx at this point is: F7FBB898
movsx   edx, al
# value of edx after this is: FFFFFFD5

# [ebp+var_E] stores 0
movzx   eax, [ebp+var_E]
movsx   eax, al
# eax = 0 here
add     eax, edx
# eax becomes FFFFFFD5
cmp     eax, 0D5h
jnz     short loc_565564E6
```

I have given the explanation and flow for each instruction below:

1. It reads a byte from the [dest] and stores it in eax.
2. Value of edx initially is: F7FBB898. After, movsx edx, al instruction it becomes FFFFFFD5. How can I make sure the value of edx will be 0x000000d5 at this point?

What should be my initial value in [dest] so that after these operation, the final value in eax is 0xd5 and not 0xFFFFFFD5

Comment: In other words, you don't want sign extension, you want zero extension.

Comment: Note that your first instruction, `movzx   eax, [ebp+dest]`, is ambiguous: it doesn't specify a size for the memory source, so it could be zero-extending a byte or a word into EAX.  And since EAX is clobbered in the next instruction, it's entirely pointless to zero-extend first into EAX before sign-extending the low byte into EDX.  `movsx edx, byte [ebp+dest]` / `movsx  eax, byte [ebp+var_E]` would be exactly equivalent to the first 4 instructions.  This is probably compiler-generated code with no or minimal optimization, resulting in braindead code like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [`movzx`](https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_209.html) (*Move with Zero-Extend*) instead of [`movsx`](https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_206.html) (*Move with Sign-Extension*) if you want to extend the value with zeros without looking at its sign.

When you use `movsx` to move `0xd5` to `edx`, it will copy the lower to bytes into `edx` and fill the remaining with the MSB of the copied value (`0xd5` = `0b11010101`, the MSB is 1), which fills the 6 remaining bytes with `0xFFFFFF`. With `movzx`, the remaining bytes are filled with `0x000000` regardless of the MSB.